# Permission Error on using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[image]

Above is the snapshot of the error I am getting while I am trying to insert data into the firebase db.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.app = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);
   this.database = this.app.database().ref().child('notes');
   this.state = {
     notes : [],
   }
}

componentWillMount() {
   const prevNotes = this.state.notes;

   this.database.on('child_added', snap => {
      prevNotes.push({
        id: snap.key,
        data: snap.val().data,
      })

   this.setState({ notes: prevNotes });
   })
}

addNote(e) {
  if(e.which === 13) {
    this.database.push().set({ data: e.target.value });
  }
}
```

Above is the react code using which I am adding notes into the db, i am making a todo list, addNote() will add a new note on keypress ENTER.

Please help me with this, I am using firebase for the first time, are there any proxy issues that might be causing this ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved , I just that to set true for the read/ write rules in the data base, firebase actually has two types of dbs Cloud firestore & realtime database.. I actually set true for the cloud db thinking I set it true for the realtime db.